# How to take an array of "strings" and put them into an array of characters in C?

Tags: c, string, function, integer, character

I have an array of characters from a struct that represent names. I can print them perfectly fine inside my main function, but if I pass them through to a different function, they're read as integers. How can I pass the same values into a function and print the name out?

For example, I currently have

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "student_struct.c"

struct Student{
    char name[50];
    int id;
    float gpa;
    int age;
};

int main(){

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("student_records.txt", "r");

    struct Student students[100] = {0};

    //Declaring fields
    int i;
    unsigned int counter = 0;

    //Take data from the file
    for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if(fscanf(fptr, "%49s %d %f %d",
            students[i].name,
            &students[i].id,
            &students[i].gpa,
            &students[i].age
        ) != 4) {
        break;
    }
        counter++;
    }

    //Creating a new names array to pass through the function
    char names[counter];
    for(i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        names[i] = *students[i].name; 
    //I see that I'm using the asterisk, which I believe is what's giving me 
    //the integer value, but when I delete it, I get an an error
    //that says "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"
    }


    //To close the file
    fclose(fptr);

    //Calling function
    calcHighGPA(names, gpas, counter);

    return 0;
}
```

As stated in the code, I cannot get the "string" value from the `struct Student` into the `char` array (`names`), I keep receiving an integer value. I also tried simply passing the `struct student->name` to the function, but that left me with the same problem. How can I take the names of the students and pass them into the function below?

The function I'm trying to call:

```
void calcHighGPA(char name[], float input[], int count){

    float highestGPA = input[1];
    int i;
    int nameGPA = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if(input[i] > highestGPA){
            highestGPA = input[i];
            nameGPA = i;
        }
    }

    printf("Student with the highest GPA: %s of %.1f\n", name[nameGPA], highestGPA);

}
```

When I call the function, the `printf` line is expecting an integer, but I'm expecting a "string".

The text file I'm reading from if needed for reference:

```
David 1234 4.0 44
Sally 4321 3.6 21
Bob 1111 2.5 20
Greg 9999 1.8 28
Heather 0000 3.2 22
Keith 3434 2.7 40
Pat 1122 1.0 31
Ann 6565 3.0 15
Mike 9898 2.0 29
Steve 1010 2.2 24
Kristie 2222 3.9 46
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `names[i] = *students[i].name;` makes `names` contain the first character from each of the `student[i].name` strings. `names` is also not *nul-terminated* and cannot be used as a string. It will be a simple array of characters. `name[nameGPA]` is a single character (which invokes *Undefined Behavior* because `"%s"` does not match`name[nameGPA]` ...)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a single string(a char array names) in calcHighGPA() while you are expecting an array of string i guess!
In the following snippet

```
char names[counter];
for(i = 0; i < counter; i++){
    names[i] = *students[i].name; 
}
```

you are not copying all the names actually. Rather you are copying the first characters of each string(string) only!

And where are you declaring and defining your gpas array that you pass to calcHighGPA?

Comment: Oops, I removed it from the post for the sake of clarity and being a bit more concise. Do you have any suggestions on how to copy each name into the array? I wasn't exactly sure what my problem was so I didn't know what to google. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @help_me you can use [strcpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) or [memcpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)  to copy all of the names to your names array, please go through the man page to use them properly